# MapBox- BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403

Tags: mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I am using Mapbox search API for autocomplete place list.But I am getting above error though i have use my valid public access token.What are the requirement to check while generating access token in mapbox.

Here is my request URl
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/bhaktapur.json?access_token=mytoken

Answer (score 0):

For me it works without problems. This appears to be due to your access token. Please read the documentation https://docs.mapbox.com/api/#access-tokens-and-token-scopes and create an access token that has the appropriate rights to perform a forward geocoding request.